# Toolbar title is not centered

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I added a `Toolbar` in my app.
For that I am using the below xml code for custom toolbar layout.

**Toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#212E42"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lefttoolbarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/righttoolbarContainer"
        android:background="#212E42">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtActionBarTitle"
            style="@style/TextViewLargeWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/fivedp"
            android:text="demo title for toolbar"
            android:visibility="visible" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/righttoolbarContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivActionBarRightTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fivedp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty_description"
            android:padding="@dimen/fivedp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chart"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivActionBarRightOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/threedp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivActionBarRightTwo"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty_description"
            android:padding="@dimen/fivedp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:visibility="gone" />



    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Android Studio output, the toolbar title is displayed in centre, as shown below.
[image]

But when I run my app, I can't get toolbar title at centre, as shown  below :
[image]

This issue raises when I add the Toolbar navigation icon dynamically in my app.
After adding the navigation icon, the icon gets its space and the toolbar title goes to the right side.

```
 mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.logo)//Toolbar navigation icon will add here
 setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

**EDIT:**
My `Toolbar` which I want to achieve is below ,For that please check updated **Toolbat.xml**:

[image]

Please, help me to get the Toolbar title centered!

Comment: Have you tried to add some margin to your TextView?

Comment: You cannot do that because home is icon is also taking space here the title is placed at center after icon placed

Comment: @Orkun Koçyiğit - I already tried to add `marginright` to titleTextview ,but its give result like [this](https://goo.gl/ieAmd8)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the textview attribute

```
android:gravity="center"
```

with this:

```
 android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Comment: It is already a centre position of layout. see `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Comment: `android:layout_gravity="center"` is not for `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove nested relativelayout and add an imageview to the relativelayout `lefttoolbarContainer`. Since your title is inParentCenter, it shouldn't move to the right when you add the image in code(atleast in theory). i.e

Toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/default_dark_blue"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lefttoolbarContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#212E42">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigationIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="56dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtActionBarTitle"
        style="@style/TextViewLargeWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/fivedp"
        android:text="demo title for toolbar"
        android:visibility="visible" />


</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And in your activity/fragment

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
ImageView navigationIcon = mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.navigationIcon);
navigationIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: I have other view to add in Toolbar child’s so I take `lefttoolbarContainer` as `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Can you explain the toolbar view you want to achieve? What are its children and where do want them?

Comment: @pRaNaY you can achieve this without nesting relativelayout.